# Messages.app not displaying messages sent while offline

Tags: messages, google, chat

Every once in a while, I will get signed out of Messages (which I use to interface with my Google Talk account) due to connectivity issues. If this happens when I am having a conversation with someone, the messages the person sends to me while I am offline are not displayed once I sign back in to Messages. Signing in to Gmail via the web interface and checking the "Chats" folder confirms that I the person I was talking to sent me some messages that I missed.

Have you also experienced this behavior, and are there are fixes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This happens to me too when using the Messages app for Google chat and Facebook chat

Comment: I've switched over to Adium for now, so I will see if the issue persists.